# Switch panes in Atom without cmd/ctrl + k?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I'd like to be able to switch between my Atom panes anytime without having to press CMD + K first before being able to switch via CMD + Up/Down/Left/Right.

Is this somehow possible?
I added this to the keymap but it doesn't work:

```
'atom-workspace':
  'cmd-up':    'window:focus-pane-above'
  'cmd-down':  'window:focus-pane-below'
  'cmd-left':  'window:focus-pane-on-left'
  'cmd-right': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks old, but incase anyone else stumbles on this - using the `.editor` context works for me:

```
'.editor':
  'ctrl-alt-cmd-shift-right': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
  'ctrl-alt-cmd-shift-left': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
  'ctrl-alt-cmd-shift-up': 'window:focus-pane-above'
  'ctrl-alt-cmd-shift-down': 'window:focus-pane-below'
```

Also, I wonder if using `cmd-left/right` would also cause an issue - on OSX `cmd` + `left/right` is a default OS shortcut for `HOME` / `END` (beginning / end of line), that might also cause a conflict.

Comment: I'd like use `ctrl-cmd-right` since it's seem not used, for fewer keypess

Answer (score 6):

```
'body':
  'ctrl-right': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
  'ctrl-left': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
```

This worked for left/right. I'm still trying to figure up and down tho

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [paner](https://atom.io/packages/paner) package!  You can implement the usual-vim `ctrl-w h` etc. to move around panes by installing this and setting up the keymap.  The documentation page has example keymaps.

Now if only they'd put a `control` key on **both** sides of the MacBook...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
'body':
  'ctrl-alt left': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
  'ctrl-alt right': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
  'ctrl-alt up': 'window:focus-pane-above'
  'ctrl-alt down': 'window:focus-pane-below'
```

press `ctrl+alt`, release, then hit your direction.